# No guarda en mi base de datos de MySQL un archivo de Excel con PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una duda acerca de el guardado de mis datos, resulta que tengo código en PHP. El cual no me permite guardar un Excel como adjunto en mi base de datos MySQL. Sin embargo, si lo guarda en la carpeta.

Aquí esta el código que manda el `form`:

```
if(isset($_POST['enter']) == 2) { 
    $query5 = "UPDATE ordenes SET que='".$_POST['que']."',firma='".$_SESSION['usuario']."', estatus='Resuelto' ,updated_at= NOW(),adjunto='".$_POST['adjunto']."' WHERE id=".$_POST['id'];
    
    if(mysqli_query($link, $query5)) {
 
        $adjunto = (isset($_FILES['adjunto'])) ? $_FILES['adjunto'] : null;
        $ruta_destino_archivo = "archivos/{$adjunto['name']}";
        $archivo_ok = move_uploaded_file($adjunto['tmp_name'], $ruta_destino_archivo);
        header("Location: index2.php");
        echo'<script type="text/javascript">
        alert("Debes Iniciar Sesion");
        window.location.href="index2.php";
        </script>';
    
    } else {

        echo "Ocurrio un error al intentar actualizar";

    }
    
}
```

Aquí recibo las variables por post para MySQL

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id']; 
    $query1 = "SELECT * FROM ordenes WHERE id =".$id;

    if($result = mysqli_query($link, $query1)) {

        while($usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
            $asunto = $usuario['asunto']; 
            $detail = $usuario['detail'];
            $adicional = $usuario['adicional'];
            $que = $usuario['que'];
            $fecha_resolucion = $usuario['fecha_resolucion'];
            $estatus = $usuario['estatus'];
    
            $adjunto = $usuario['adjunto']['type'];
        }

    }
    
}
```

Con `var_dump` me arroja lo siguiente:

> string(126) "UPDATE ordenes SET que='agregabdo podemos aui',firma='Rmendoza', estatus='Resuelto' ,updated_at= NOW(),adjunto='' WHERE id=210"
> y aqui muestro una foto de como si me sube los archivos en la carpeta

[image: mysql]

Comment: Primero deberías mover el archivo a la ubicación final y, solo si se pudo mover, realizar la consulta. Luego, supongo que `$_POST['adjunto']` debería mostrar un error o advertencia de índice no definido, porque corresponde a `$_FILES`.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo resolví tenia que guardar el `name` del adjunto
dentro del código de `update`. De esta forma:

```
adjunto='".$adjunto["name"]."'
```

Comment: si ya la termine y haci lo resolvi

Comment: Cierto. Mi error. Elimine mi comentario.

Comment: ? pero yo soy el autor